# Why does Moment function return 'not a function'?

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

This works in localhost but not in production where I get `ERROR TypeError: n.endOf is not a function`

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

changeMaxDate(maxTime: moment.Moment) {
    if (maxTime) {
        return maxTime.endOf('day').toISOString();
    }
}
```

I have read all other Moment questions and docs to no avail.

I have tried `import moment from 'moment';` (this works too) and other ways without success

Moment.js 2.24.0

TS 3.5.3

Angular 8.2.3

```
<input matInput
                   [matDatepicker]="maxTime"
                   [(ngModel)]="data.maxTime"
                   (ngModelChange)="changeMaxDate(data.maxTime)"
                   placeholder="{{ 'yyyy-mm-dd' | translate }}">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="maxTime"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #maxTime></mat-datepicker>
```

maxTime from datepicker in localhost

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: {…}, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…},                     
_locale: Locale, …}
_d: Mon Nov 04 2019 23:59:59 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
__proto__: Object
_i: {year: 2019, month: 10, date: 4}
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate:                 "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0),     overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__: Object
```

and in production it's a string
`Mon Nov 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

Comment: try to change the changeMaxDate parameter just to maxTime: moment

Comment: Thx, tried that. Error `Cannot use namespace 'moment' as a type.`

Comment: which version of momentjs do you use?

Comment: Latest Moment.js 2.24.0

Comment: would you please tell how you call the changeMaxDate(...) method?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/

Have you tried changing `compilerOptions` ?

Or: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1194#issuecomment-381488271

Comment: You said that in localhost everything works? Would you please check where the moment package is added in package.json?

Comment: Under "dependencies": {

Comment: in angular.json do you have added in scripts section the moment js? ```"scripts": [
                "node_modules/moment/moment.js" ],``` ? This is in architect -> build -> options part for your project

Comment: I have `"moduleResolution": "node"` and `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` (needed for other parts)

Comment: > in angular.json do you have added in scripts section the moment js?

No

Comment: angular.json

`"scripts": [ "build": "yarn run build-tools && ng build -c build"...`

What is this `architect -> build -> options` ??

Comment: @JohanFaerch, not in package.json but angular.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203095/discussion-between-nikola-yankov-and-johan-faerch).

Comment: Have you looked into the example provided on the angular material page for momentJs? https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples (scroll down a little to "Datepicker that uses Moment.js dates")? If you could provide a minimal https://stackblitz.com/  repro maybe solving the problem would be easier :)

Comment: Thx @mortom123 Not much info there. The datepicker works and passes a moment object to the function but this single function then fails in production

Comment: Can you print the `maxTime` object during runtime and show the output?

Comment: Will do in about 15 min (build time)

Comment: Production `Mon Nov 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

Answer (score 0):

What data are you passing as parameter? In your case I believe moment.Moment is of type **any**. In this case the condition if (maxTime) will return true even if you will pass some empty object {} or Date. But this objects does not have *endOf* function defined.

You can do like this:

```
changeMaxDate(maxTime: moment.Moment) {
    if (maxTime && typeof maxTime.endOf === 'function') {
        return maxTime.endOf('day').toISOString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.module`, add `MomentDateAdapter` like below to your providers to actually use moment with matDatepicker

```
{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
{provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
```

and import them from `@angular/material`

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick tip using `[(ngModel)]` and `(ngModelChange)` together, might be not doing exactly what you intend, because `[(ngModel)]` is already binding changes. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-
Furthermore I think the output is not in the correct format for your function.

Comment: Thx. Will look into this. `maxTime` is of type `moment` so nothing wrong with that at the moment (no pun intended ;)